# Can I install WhizzyTeX for Emacs on a Mac (is Mac OS X a unix environment)?

Tags: macos, unix, emacs

I think my question is pretty stupid, but here it goes:

I am using Aquamacs, and I want to install the [WhizzyTeX](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/) mode. The website for WhizzyTeX says that "it is designed for Unix platforms".

I read that Mac OS X is unix certified, but does that mean I can install WhizzyTeX on my mac? If yes, can I install and use it with Aquamacs or do I have to use the Emacs running from the terminal?

**PS**: I don't know whether this question should be posted here or on SuperUser, but as Emacs users seem to hang out here more often, this is the place I chose.

**EDIT**: There are some [websites](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/9289) saying I can use WhizzyTeX with Carbon Emacs on mac os x, but some places say I cannot (see for example [this](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CEEQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcyberaide.googlecode.com%2Fsvn-history%2Fr3274%2Ftrunk%2Flectures%2Fgridcomputing%2Fnotes.pdf&ei=x_USTO2dG5ClcdDtzY4M&usg=AFQjCNEr2t-p2jNyaVqUmHLgJqx47KXZnQ) pdf document, page 27, which says that "* whizzytex: http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/ mode in latex with ocaml good fo linux, should also work in cygwin, doe not work on osx"). So I am really confused...

Comment: I think I found it!!!!  http://www.math.columbia.edu/~lipshitz/MathOnMac.html  . I will try now and if I am successful I will write something here again. Yay!

Comment: Stupid questions don't exist.

Comment: BTW, yes Mac OS X is now a POSIX compliant Unix. - Also, I'd recommend using the Cocoa Emacs.app instead of Aquamacs, you'll get a more uniform Emacs experience that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I managed to make it. It is a bit slow and I think some files have issues, but in any case, it works!

The trick is to do what is explained [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~lipshitz/MathOnMac.html) except for step 4. What I did instead was put the whizzytex.sty file in the same place as whizzytex.el and whizzytex (see step 5 in the article) and then I opened the file whizzytex (the one without extension), and where it says:

> name (or full path) of the dump latex2e package file (without the extension)
>   PACKAGE=whizzytex.sty

I changed it to the path where I put whizzytex.sty. In my case I have:

> PACKAGE=/Users/viviannevilar/.emacs.d/packages/whizzytex.sty

I hope this is useful for someone  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install with the software distribution system [Macports](http://www.macports.org):

```
sudo port install tex-whizzytex
```

You only have to set up your emacs configuration files afterwards.

Have fun!

Comment: At this point I have managed to install it, but I hope your answer is useful to someone  :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?title=Editors) site (scrolled about 3/4's the way down) it says that it can be installed on Mac OS. It pretty much just says:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I had seen this page before and had forgotten about it. In any case, they say "Instructions for installing *WhizzyTeX* on Mac OS X can be found on this WizzyTeX page. Note that these instructions are both out of date and misleading in various ways". The link on the *WhizzyTeX* word redirects to a page that says nothing about WhizzyTeX or its installation procedures (http://www.esm.psu.edu/mac-tex/WizzyTeX.html). Finally, if I can install it on my mac, will I be able to use it with Aquamacs or do I have to use Emacs from the terminal?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the 'out of date' instruction comment as well, but it does say that it installs, on OSX, with just the above make/install (kind of misleading I know). I'm not sure about Aquamacs though, I've never really used it.

Comment: The full installation instructions are missing is a problem for me, but I also want to know if I can use it with Aquamacs if I do manage to install it. My question here is not really about Aquamacs per se, the same question applies to Emacs not run from the terminal on mac OS (Emacs.app ?)

Comment: Are you just looking for some LaTeX editing?? If so will this work? http://aquamacs.org/latex.shtml

Comment: Oh, no, Aquamacs comes with Auctex + preview-latex by default, I have and use those options. WhizzyTex, though, would show me what I am typing as I do it. I am mostly interested in having it so I can use when drawing TikZ pictures. I will update my question with a couple of things I found, when you can have a look. Thanks for all your help, it is good to know that I am not alone  :)